# How to parse a list of Dictionarys (List<Dictionary<string, string>>) using linq

Tags: c#, linq, csv

### My Situation

I've written an aplication that has multiple dropdown fields. The user can select something in one field which updates the other fields.
The other fields may only have entrys that match the other fields. To know what is valid, I use a SQL-Table.

### Example

```
ID | fruit1 |   fruit2   | taste
---------------------------------
 1 | apple  | strawberry | sweet  
 2 | banana | strawberry | sweet  
 3 | apple  | lemon      | sour
 4 | kiwi   | apple      | sour
```

at first the user can decide between 2 options in each field.

```
fruit1: "apple"/"banana"/"kiwi"
fruit2: "lemon"/"strawberry"/"apple"
color: "sweet"/"sour"
```

if he selects "strawberry" as fruit2 than in the other fields there should only be options where "strawberry" is in the fruit2 column.

```
fruit1: "apple"/"banana"
fruit2: "strawberry"
color: "sweet"
```

### The Problem

My current implementation is very slow. After each change there has to be a new query. But with each query there is a change which results in another query. The latency adds up and makes the process very slow.

### What I want to do

My idea now is to only do a sqlquery once for each field (I have to do this).

### What I already did

My first idea was to write a second application that pulls all data from the table and puts it in an csv-file.
Then I have to parse that file for the information. I couldn't get oledb to work with the file so I searched for another way.
I'm currently looking at Linq to parse the file. I'm reading the file and putting its content in an List< Dictionary< string, string>>

### My Code

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> _data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>{new Dictionary<string, string>{{"fruit1","apple"},{"fruit2","strawberry"},{"color","red"}},new Dictionary<string, string>{{"fruit1","banana"}, {"fruit2","lemon"}, {"color","yellow"}},new Dictionary<string, string>{{"fruit1","apple"}, {"fruit2","lemon"}, {"color","green"}}};

var r = _data
    .Select(i => i.Values).Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>()
    .Where(d => d.ContainsValue("apple"));
    .SelectMany(s=>s);
```

Which results in an empty result. The Result should be again a List< Dictionary< string, string>>;

### My Question

What is the most performant/reliable way of doing this? Downloading the CSV and reading it or doing a query and saving all data (just like the csv)?
How would a Linq-query look like that can parse the List< Dictionary< string, string>>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would this be slow, considering you have indexes on the fields already? It would be simply a query either in plain SQL or with Linq:

-SQL:

```
select * from myTable where fruit2 = 'Strawberry'
```

-Linq:

```
var choices = db.MyTable.Where( f => f.Fruit2 == "Strawberry" );
```

If you want to bring all data to client side once anyway, then your first option could be a simple List. ie:

```
var data = db.MyTable.ToList();
```

Then you could do the queries client side with Linq:

```
var choices = data.Where( f => f.Fruit2 == "Strawberry");
```

If the data is huge to keep in a list, client side then you could something like SQLite for persistence. It doesn't need any installation and you could save its data to IsolatedStorage or AppData. Using a CSV instead is not a good idea IMHO. You can't have indexes in a CSV at least.

Comment: SQLite is perfect for my application. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want parse Dictionary to object...

```
_data.Select(i => i.Values).Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>()
    .Where(d => d.ContainsValue("apple"))
    .SelectMany(s=>s).ToList().ForEach((item) =>
            {

                item.Key
                item.Value...
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, lets create a classe to represent your table

```
class SampleClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Fruit1 { get; set; }
    public string Fruit2 { get; set; }
    public string Taste { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will do your SQL query to get date from table and store this in memory, using `List<SampleClass>` like that:

```
List<SampleClass> data = GetDataFromDatabase();
```

Then you must fill itens in dropdownlist

```
dropDown1.Items = data.Select(d => d.Fruit1);
dropDown2.Items = data.Select(d => d.Fruit2);
dropDown3.Items = data.Select(d => d.Fruit3);
```

When dropdown2 change, you can use linq to filter only data that Fruit2 == valueInDropDown2, like that:

```
//When dropDown2 change
var selectedValueInDropDown2 = "strawberry";

dropDown1.Items = data.Where(x => x.Fruit2 == selectedValueInDropDown2).Select(d => d.Fruit1);
dropDown3.Items = data.Where(x => x.Fruit2 == selectedValueInDropDown2).Select(d => d.Fruit3);
```